# Gridview to Excel file - save output instead of showing it

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have this code below which takes my GridView, populates it, and generates and opens an Excel file with the griddata in my browser.

What if I want to save that file directly to my server or attach it to an email message, instead of the display prompt that automatically pops up.

Can I do that with small modifications to the script?

```
protected void btnExcelExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e) 
{ 
    HtmlForm form = new HtmlForm(); 

    Response.Clear(); 
    Response.Buffer = true; 
    Response.Charset = ""; 
    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", string.Format("attachment;filename={0}", "Student.xls")); 
    Response.ContentType = "application/ms-excel"; 

    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter(); 
    HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw); 

    GridView1.AllowPaging = false; 
    BindGridDetails(GridView1); 

    form.Attributes["runat"] = "server"; 
    form.Controls.Add(GridView1); 
    this.Controls.Add(form); 
    form.RenderControl(hw); 

    string style = @"<!--mce:2-->"; 
    Response.Write(style); 
    Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString()); 
    Response.Flush(); 
    Response.End(); 
}
```

Comment: You are not generating an actual Excel file. You're generating an HTML file that is being served to the client with an Excel extension. This causes problems. In clients that know how to handle this, the user will see a message warning them about a corrupted file. In clients that don't know how to handle this, they'll just say the file is corrupted and refuse to open it. Instead, you should generate an actual Excel file with Open XML SDK, NPOI, or EPPlus (my favorite).

Answer (score 0):

you can save your grid data as a Comma Separated Value file on the server and email or save it directly on your server.
CSV files can be opened using Excel.